# Is it possible to use Google Places API in Xamarin.Forms on UWP? If so, how? If not, what can be used instead?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I don't really know what might be needed, so I'll describe the problem. I need to make routes from several points for the program. I thought to use Google maps to display the path and the points themselves and Google places to search and select these points, but from everything I found, I realized that Google places only go to phones. So is it possible to somehow use this API for UWP? If so, how? If not, what can be used instead?

Comment: This article can help you. Here is the website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api

Comment: Using the Google Places API shouldn't be a problem since its a REST api, you can call that from anywhere. Displaying a path on a map might be a problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was not talking about Google Maps, but about Google Places. Like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9WHrc3ffYY. Only all such videos talk about phones, but I need it for UWP. Maybe I'm missing something, so I apologize in advance.

Comment: I couldn't find something about UWP in the Google Maps API and I asked my colleague and he also said Google Maps doesn't support UWP.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll think about what I can use instead.